# What is this constructor name with dot

Tags: dart, flutter

In flutter's Image widget, I found the use of constructor name with dot (.) like Image.asset() and Image.file().

What is it and how it is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [named constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#named-constructors)

> Use a named constructor to implement multiple constructors for a class
>   or to provide extra clarity:
>
> ```
> class Point {   
>
>   num x, y;
>
>   Point(this.x, this.y);
>
>   // Named constructor   
>   Point.origin() {
>     x = 0;
>     y = 0;   
>   } 
> }
> ```